# left align using alignat?

Tags: align, alignat

I want to align some equations on the left side in a document. And additionally I want to have some aligned text behind every equation. Also the equations need to be numbered. With the code below my goal is almost achieved. I just need to bring the text aligned to the right... How do I do that? Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    &u_\mathrm{L} = L \cdot \frac{\text{d}i_\mathrm{L}}{\text{d}t} \quad(\text{Differentialform}) &\label{eq:2_19} \\
    &i_\mathrm{L} = \frac{1}{L} \cdot \int\limits_t u_\mathrm{L} \text{d}t + i_\mathrm{L}(t=0) \quad (\text{Integralform}) &\label{eq:2_20}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... or just rearrange ampersands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign}
u_\mathrm{L}    &   = L \cdot \frac{\text{d}i_\mathrm{L}}{\text{d}t}       
    &       
                &   \text{(Differentialform)}       &       &   \\
i_\mathrm{L}    & = \frac{1}{L} \cdot \int\limits_t u_\mathrm{L} \text{d}t + i_\mathrm{L}(t=0)     
    &       
                &   \text{(Integralform)}           &       &   
    \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just a matter of using `\mathllap`from the `mathtools` package for (part of) the longest equation:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
& u_\mathrm{L} = L · \frac{\text{d}i_\mathrm{L}}{\text{d}t} & & \text{(Differentialform)} & & \label{eq:2_19} \\
& \mathrlap{i_\mathrm{L} = \frac{1}{L} · \int\limits_t u_\mathrm{L} \text{d}t + i_\mathrm{L}(t=0) } & & \text{(Integralform)} & & \label{eq:2_20}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want the text all the way on the right side. I want the text to start on the same height. say \qquad behind the end of the longer equation.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you want. I'll modify my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Dave: I modified my answer. Hope the spacing is correct for you.

Comment: I got some conflict with the mathtools package. I will try your solution at some other point. The solution with rearranging the ampersands is the easiest solution I guess.

Comment: Strange… In my opinion, mathtools is one of the really fundamental packages for maths, as it extends amsmath (and corrects two bugs).

Comment: I got the error: "No room for a new \dimen . \ch@ck ... \else \errmessage {No room for a new #3} \fi l.56 \newdimen\Gm@layoutheight". seen something like that before? I apply the other solution since it works just fine. maybe not the most elegant way.

Comment: It seems to be linked with the `geometry` package (\Gm@layoutheight is defined in the internals of geometry), which my code doesn't use. Maybe try adding  `\usepackage{etex}` to see what happens. I don't know of any incompatibilities of `mathtools` with another package (btw, it loads `amsmath`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[fleqn]` option to the `amsmath` pacakge and and control the left indent via the `\mathindent` length:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

{%\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}% <-- brace group to keep these changes local.
\begin{alignat}{3}
    u_\mathrm{L} &= L \cdot \frac{\text{d}i_\mathrm{L}}{\text{d}t} &&\quad(\text{Differential form}) &\label{eq:2_19} \\
   i_\mathrm{L} &= \frac{1}{L} \cdot \int\limits_t u_\mathrm{L} \text{d}t + i_\mathrm{L}(t=0)  &&\quad(\text{Integral form}) \label{eq:2_20}
\end{alignat}
}

\end{document}
```