# Left-align equations in the alignat environment, like in flalign

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, alignat, flalign

I would like to left-align a few equations inside the `alignat*` environment, but I am not sure how to achieve this. Essentially, what I want is something that behaves like `flalign`but lets me align the terms just like `alignat`.
However, using `fleqn` to align all equations in the document is not an option for me, since I only want to left-align them in one instance.
I looked around and found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171141/left-align-using-alignat) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429281/alignat-but-starting-at-the-left). I don't think that these answer my question though, but I am fairly new to using LaTeX, so please forgive my cluelessness in case they do.

If there is a way to create a list and then align the terms in the list that would also work for me, however I got the warning message that I cannot use lists inside a math environment, but that is the only way I know how to align equations.

Example with all the packages I use in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem} % I use this because I want to number my theorems myself
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
  {\endinnercustomthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{customthm}{5.3.9}[Properties of the transpose]
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\textbf{\textup{(a) }} (A+B)^T &&= A^T + B^T \qquad && \forall ~n \times n \text{ matrices A and B}. \\
    &\textbf{\textup{(b) }} (kA)^T &&= kA^T  && \forall \text{ matrices A, scalars k}. \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{customthm}
\end{document}
```

The way it is aligned is great, but I need it to be on the left. As I mentioned above, if there is a way to make a list and align it from within that list, then that would also be great (even better maybe, since I wouldn't have to put (a), (b), etc. myself), but I couldn't figure out how to do this. Thanks a lot in advance, I hope I formulated the question clearly.

[image: Current output. I want Theorem 5.3.9 to be on the left.]

P.S.: In case you are wondering why I need this, I am only writing a summary for myself right now, but would like to get better in LaTeX, hence I'm doing it this way, two birds with one stone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more appropriate here to set the list of items in the theorem using a regular list. Since you're loading [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) already, formatting of the list elements is easy. Together with [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`, you can set the horizontal alignment across `\item`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem,eqparbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Properties of the transpose]
  \begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\textbf{\textup{(a) }} (A+B)^T &&= A^T + B^T \qquad && \forall ~n \times n \text{ matrices A and B}. \\
    &\textbf{\textup{(b) }} (kA)^T &&= kA^T  && \forall \text{ matrices A, scalars k}.
  \end{alignat*}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Properties of the transpose]
  \mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\upshape(\alph*)}, ref=(\alph*)]
    \item $\eqmakebox[LHS][l]{$(A+B)^T$} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$A^T + B^T~$} \forall~n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$.
    \item $\eqmakebox[LHS][l]{$(kA)^T$}  = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$kA^T$}       \forall~n$ matrices $A$, scalars $k$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Could you tell me what the difference is between the empty `\mbox` argument and something like `~\\ ` ? To me it looks like the latter makes the vertical offset a bit bigger, but can/should I always use `\mbox{}` in situation like these? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Cannot edit my earlier comment for whatever reason. Just wanted to add that `~` seems - to my layman's eye at least -  to do the same as `\mbox{}`...

Comment: @davebc112: It's similar. They're may be problems when the theorem is at the bottom of the page, since the start of a list can be used as a possible page break.

Comment: Ok, I shall use `\mbox{}` in these situations then. Just a small follow-up question: Is there a way to use alignment character `&` in lists? I added a `\qquad` in front of the `\forall` on all five lines, but out of interest (and a bit of lazyness), is there a (simple) way to only add the spacing once and then just align the other `\forall`s at that point?

Comment: @davebc112: The alignment character `&` does not work within a list. I'd suggest including the `\qquad` as part of the `\eqmakebox[RHS][l]` that is the largest. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) stores the maximum width by `<tag>`, so adding it to the largest (widest) element would necessarily add it to all other `\eqmakebox[RHS][l]`'s.